# Galactic Empress with nude female guards book

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a SF book many (40-50?) years ago but I can barely remember any plot or characters.

Only one thing sticks in my mind, there was like a galactic empress and, chained before her throne, she had maybe half a dozen 'nekkid wimmin' to act as her final bodyguards - I think they had brain implants to keep them hostile to anyone in the throne room....

Comment: Funny the things that stick in your head... :-D

Comment: Was she Martian Princess Dejah Thoris? See comic John Carter Warlord of Mars #11 1977.  Also I need to realize 50 years ago isn't 1930 anymore :-(

Comment: Rather than editing a comment on the answer into your question, you should probably just post that as a comment on the answer itself. :)

Comment: Total tangent, but having your bodyguards chained to anything seems like a bad idea. That would surely hamper their movements in any sort of fight, and I would think the whole point of bodyguards is that they be able to fight under any conditions as best as possible.

Comment: @lucasbachmann Yes, as an old person, I frequently find myself saying, "Let's see was that two weeks ago? A month? Oh, no, it was 1973."

Comment: Looking at the **Deathstalker** answer by John Rennie (now accepted) it's very obvious that I totally misremembered when I read the book ....almost 30 years, not 40 or 50!

Comment: @V2Blast  Yeah, I've done that now, cheers for the guidance

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Is it possible you have mis-remembered when you read the book and it might have been Simon R. Green's [Deathstalker series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41588-deathstalker) starting in 1994?

If so the empress is her Imperial Majesty Lionstone XIV aka the *Iron Bitch*. Her bodyguards are euphemistically referred to as *maids-in-waiting*, they are naked and they are cybernetically enhanced. In the first book *Deathstalker* we read:

> The Empress sat casually on a great throne of black iron and gleaming jade, set just high enough to keep her feet out of the water. She looked perfectly at ease, even though the throne had obviously been designed for someone rather larger. The mists curled away from where she sat, calm and comfortable in her own little circle of cool air. She looked cold and regal and perfect in her royal robes and diamond crown, every inch an Empress. Her maids-in-waiting crouched naked in the muddy waters at the base of the throne, like so many hunting dogs straining at unseen leashes.

And in the third book *Deathstalker War*:

> At the base of her Throne, her maids-in-waiting crouched watchfully like the guard dogs they were. Naked and unashamed as animals, mindwiped and surgically altered to be loyal unto death, they watched the Court through cybernetic senses, ready for any threat to their beloved mistress. They would kill or die to protect her, and their ferocity was legendary. Their teeth were pointed and their fingers ended in implanted steel claws. Within their naked bodies they had other, nastier surprises, the best that money could buy. Once they had been as human as anyone else, with minds and lives of their own, but that was before Lionstone chose them, and took them away from their old lives to be a part of hers. They could be commoner or aristocrat; all were made equally vile under Lionstone's wishes. No one objected. No one dared. Besides, it was an honor to be a maid-in-waiting to the Empress.

I make no comment on the reasons why I immediately recognised your description :-)

Comment: "Their teeth were pointed and their fingers ended in implanted steel claws."  This is, of course, why range weapons were invented.

Comment: I'd like to know what were the '...other, nastier surprises,...".

Comment: Any other passages you could list for us? For science.